# ¿Por qué no inicia automáticamente mi APP al iniciar o reiniciar el celular?

Tags: android-studio, boot

Hace un tiempo hice una APP, la cual al prender o reiniciar el celular cargaba el Activity principal de la APP luego de unos segundos de estar encendido el celular. Ahora que cambie de celular y quise instalar la APP, tuve que hacer algunos cambios para que funcionara. La APP funciona bien, sin embargo la función que hace que se inicialice la APP cuando se prende o reinicialice el celular no funciona, a pesar de que he cambiado el código con múltiples opciones que he visto en el foro. La versión actual de mi teléfono es android 12.

Incluso coloque un Toast, para verificar que si se estuviera ejecutando la clase BroadcastReceiver. El Toast se muestra pero no se ejecuta el MainActivity.

Leí que para que funcione esta opción, luego de instalar la APP el usuario debe abrir la APP manualmente la primera vez, para que las siguientes veces con el encendido o reinicio del celular ya lo haga sin problemas, de lo contrario no funciona. Probe pero no paso nada.

La versión 12 de android pide algún permiso adicional, sera eso lo que falta? o adicionar alguna libreria en el build.grandle?

Dejo el código de lo ultimo que tengo, cualquier sugerencia muchas gracias.

Clase BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Inicio extends BroadcastReceiver {
 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals)) {

    Intent iniciar = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    iniciar.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    context.startActivity(iniciar);

Toast.makeText(Context, "iniciando APP", Toast.LENGHT.SHORT).show();

}

}

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<activity
  android:name".MainActivity"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent_filter>
</activity> 

<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".Inicio" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIBE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```